# Statistical Programme R- using one category of continous data?

Tags: r, math, statistics

I'm using R, trying to use data I've been given to plot a boxplot. One of the categories is "sex", with (obviously) either "M" or "F". How do I exclude females, so I can use the male data to create a boxplot? I'm new to R, any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Okay, I managed to make a vector(??) only including male data using newdata<-subset(olympic, sex=="M"). Now how do I do the same but with two subsets of a different category of continous data? Is it similar notation? (E.g. say the category is "hair" with different colours, and I want "blonde" and "ginger")

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make a reproducible example

Comment: Okay thank you! I just want two boxplots plotted simultaneously, so I'll just use the same method as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `boxplot(, subset = )`

I don't have data, so only direct you to `subset` argument.

I think as a general guideline, check documentation page of an R function first **before asking** on SO. R functions, especially those producing summary plots, are **very powerful** as they often have **many** arguments offering very flexible options. See `?boxplot' in this case.

Answer (score 1):

try to boxplot on male_data

```
male_data <- data[data$sex == "M",]
```